# Why Mapbox gl changes its style without changing state with setStyle call only in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mapbox-gl-js

I thought react components depend on state to change/render view but why calling setStyle function of mapbox-gl changes the style of the map without changing the state?

```
class WebMap extends React.Component {
state = {

    style:"mapbox://styles/noeltech/cj6jcxggi5jpr2smhnsb42h3i",
    lng:122.5683,
    lat:10.7028,
    zoom:14
};
componentDidMount(){
    const {lng, lat,zoom,style } = this.state;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.mapContainer,
        style: style,
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom
    });

    map.on('move', () => {
        const {lng, lat } =map.getCenter();

        this.setState({
            lng: lng.toFixed(4),
            lat: lat.toFixed(4),
            zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
        });
        console.log(`lng: ${lng}  lat:${lat}`)
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{
        // this.setState({style:"mapbox://styles/noeltech/cj6zr2fda9jyz2smst427o4gb"})
        map.setStyle("mapbox://styles/noeltech/cj6zr2fda9jyz2smst427o4gb")
        console.log(this.state.style)
    },5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

the map variable is a reference for the instance of Mapbox map, so when you are making the `map.setStyle()`, you're changing the style of this reference instance and `this.state` is the state of the current component that you're wrapping the `map-container`. The internal changing will not trigger a outside state change, only if the map instance has, for example, some listener for this like onStyleChange()

Comment: Thanks for the reference insights..now I get it

Answer (score -1):

Im missing a code in my setState Function I have to add:

```
   function() {
                map.setStyle(this.state.style)
```

Like this

```
   setTimeout(()=>{
        this.setState({
            style: "mapbox://styles/noeltech/cj6zr2fda9jyz2smst427o4gb"
        },
            function() {
                map.setStyle(this.state.style)
            }
        )        
    },5000);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Is a comment to the answer or an edit to the question. Also you should really consider accepting the answer that fixed your issue or at least vote their answer, if you feel like it wasn't the full answer but it helped you. You can also suggest edits to people commentary if you feel they can be improved.